# Does it say anywhere in Halacha that a person shouldn’t eat where others Arnt eating?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, rabbis, derech-eretz-manners, derech

BH

Does it say anywhere that a person shouldn’t eat where others are eating so they won’t feel hungry while the person is eating?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adECZemJ2o4

Answer (score 1):

[Bava Kamma 92b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.92b.10?lang=bi):

> אֲמַר לֵיהּ רָבָא לְרַבָּה בַּר מָרִי, מְנָא הָא מִילְּתָא דְאָמְרִי
> אִינָשֵׁי: שִׁיתִּין תִּכְלֵי מַטְיוּהּ לְכַכָּא דְּקָל חַבְרֵיהּ
> שְׁמַע, וְלָא אֲכַל? אֲמַר לֵיהּ, דִּכְתִיב: ״וְלִי אֲנִי עַבְדֶּךָ
> וּלְצָדֹק הַכֹּהֵן וְלִבְנָיָהוּ בֶן יְהוֹיָדָע וְלִשְׁלֹמֹה עַבְדְּךָ
> לֹא קָרָא״.

> Rava said to Rabba bar Mari: What is the Torah source for
> the popular saying of *sixty aches hit the teeth of someone who hears
> his friend eating, but he's not eating*? He replied: from the verse in
> Kings Ch. 1: [Adinoya has invited others to his massive feast], *but
> I, your servant ... and Shlomo your servant were not invited.*

(Of course in context, the invite list to that party was showing Adoniya's plan to rule after King David's death, and his very clear ideas about who would be *in* and who would be *out* -- but the Talmud is using it here loosely as pointing out that yes, when the other guy has food and you don't, it hurts.)

There's also the point about the prohibition of plowing with an ox and donkey together; the ox is a ruminant and always chewing, which makes the donkey jealous ...